# Dugundji problem about quasicomponents.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Problem 5 part d), of chapter V, section 3 (p. 118):

> d. In $E^2$ let $L_1$ be the line $x=1$ and $L_2$ the line $x=-1$. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $R_n$ be the rectangle $\{(x,y):|x|\le \frac{n}{n+1},|y|\le n\}$. Finally, let $Y$ be the subspace $L_1\cup L_2\cup \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+} Fr(R_n)$ of $E^2$. Show: The component of $(1,0)$ is $L_1$ and the quasi-component of $(1,0)$ is $L_1\cup L_2$.

I can see why the component of $(1,0)$ is $L_1$, that's just using the definition. However I can't see why the quasicomponent is $L_1\cup L_2$, well intuitively it makes sense, because when $n\to\infty$, the rectangle $R_n$ looks like (or may I say, *exactly like*) the *stripe* formed by $L_1\cup L_2$, do I have to show explicitly that $L_1\cup L_2 \subseteq \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+} Fr(R_n)$? I don't know this makes sense at times.

---

Definition of quasi-component:

> In a space $X$, define $x\sim y$ if there is no decomposition of $X$ into two disjoint open sets, one of which contains $x$ and the other $y$. A quasi-component is the equivalent class of such relation.

I take as follows, if $Q_X(x)$ is a quasi component, then $Q_X(x)=\{y: \text{if $x,y\in A$ then $A$ is a connected set}\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*I'll use $\partial$ instead of $\text{Fr}$ if you don't mind, I'm just more used to it*.)

You have to show that for $x=(1,0)$ and $y\in L_2$ there is no separation of $X$ between $x$ and $y$. A separation would  amount to a clopen set containing $x$ (and thus $L_1$) but not containing $y$. If $S$ is such a clopen subset of $X$ with $x\in S$, can you show that it intersects arbitrarily large $∂R_n$? Can you conclude that $S$ must contain $L_2$, using the fact that $∂R_n$ is connected for each $n$?

Don't forget that you also have to show that for a point $z\in X\setminus(L_1\cup L_2$), there does exist a separation of $X$ between $x$ and $z$.

Comment: Thank you! When you ask "can you show that it intersects arbitrarily large $Fr(R_n)$?" I think now that that's the core of the problem isn't it? But I don't know how to show that exactly without thinking in _calculus_, I mean, saying things  like "if we let $n$ tend to infinity then..."

Comment: @AnaGalois: Yes, thinking about what happens when $n$ tends to $\infty$ would go in the right direction. The clopen set $S$ is an open neighborhood about $x=(1,0)$, and the $∂R_n$ become closer and closer to $x$, as $(\frac n{n+1},0)→(1,0)$.

Comment: Oh! yes I see, thank you!